# How to show number 4 digit (0000,0001) number using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want my output as 0000, 0001, 0002. If i use normal js math then the result come 0,1,2

```
var count=0000+1;
document.write(count);
```

Output is **1**

But i want output as **0001**

how to do this?

Comment: You can make it a string

Comment: Did you solve your question?

Answer (score 4):

The `+` operator in Javascript is used for both addition and concatenating depending on the operands. `0000+1` is just *adding* zero and one, which gives one. You can *concatenate* the string `"000"` to the number `1` and it will give you the string `"0001"`, which is what you're looking for.

Here's a function that will always have 4 digits, with leading zeros. It works by concatenating the string `"000"` and your number, then shortening, if needed, to 4 characters.

```
function pad(n) {
    var s = "000" + n;
    return s.substr(s.length-4);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use lodash's [padStart](https://lodash.com/docs#padStart)

You can use it like:

```
var count = 1;
_.padStart(count, 4, '0');
//this will give you 0001
_.padStart(23, 4, '0');
//this will give you 0023
```

Comment: This is so much simpler!

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
var count = 1;
document.write( '0000'.substr( String(count).length ) + count  );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using integer, but you can do something like,

"000"+1

output => "0001"

P.S: Maybe if you share your use case, I can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Add the zeros and then remove the ones that are left over:

```
function renameArtboards(){  
     var docRef = app.activeDocument;  
     var aB = docRef.artboards;  
     for(var a=0;a<aB.length;a++){  
          var curAB = aB[a];  
          var sNumber = "000" + [a+1];
          curAB.name = sNumber.substr(sNumber.length-4);
     }  
}  
renameArtboards();
```

Comment: Hello Carlos, welcome to Stack Overflow. While your answer might yield the correct results in your environment, the questin is a general JavaScript question. There is no `app.activeDocument.artboeards` in a vanilla JavaScript environment. Please edit your question to only contain its essential part in relation to the question. (Which should be line 6 and 7 of your code)

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm an year and a half late but I happen to need this kind of logic in my app right now. The most "elegant" solution in my opinion is this one:

```js
const yourNumber = 32;
const defaultFill = "0000"

const formattedNumber = (defaultFill + yourNumber).substr(String(yourNumber).length)
```

This one works just fine for my use-case. It may have some limits if you have to handle numbers with more than 4 digits – in that case you could lose some information on the way. Be aware of that.

I hope this helped you, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
var JobNumber = 'JB-00000';
var digistextraction = JobNumber.substr(3,5);

var JobNumberTable=[];
for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    k=1;
    digistextraction = parseInt(digistextraction) + k;
    JobNumberTable.push('JB-' + digistextraction.toLocaleString(undefined, {useGrouping: false, minimumIntegerDigits: 5}));
    k++;
}
console.log(JobNumberTable);
```

Answer (score -1):

Best way is

```
var NumberWithLeadingZeroes = "000" + 1;
alert(NumberWithLeadingZeroes);//Will give you "0001"
```

**UPDATE**

```
function NumberWithLeadingZeroes (n)
{
    if ( n< 10 )
    {
        return ( '000' + n.toString () );
    }
    else if ( n< 100 )
    {
        return ( '00' + n.toString () );
    }
    else if ( n< 1000 )
    {
        return ( '0' + n.toString () );
    }
    else
    {
        return ( n);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would result in a 5 digit number if your value was > 9. (ie: `00010`)

Comment: @BrianD OP asked for only 4 digit number.

Comment: OP asked for a 4 digit number where there are leading 0s to make up the difference in length. Your solution will only create a 4 digit number in a very small solution set.